# Adding reactive values to a dataframe - Rshiny

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, reactive-programming

At the moment I am attempting the following: import a file in Rshiny, give it a number (interactive), and then move on to the next file. This part works fine. However, I would also like to store the data of every iteration, and then show it on the user interface.
However, it is not working. So I guess something is not right with the reactivity, but I am not sure how to fix it.

```
ui<-fluidPage(
    mainPanel(
        radioButtons(inputId="score",label="Give a score",choices=c(1:9),selected=1),
        actionButton(inputId="new","Next file"),
        tableOutput("savdat")
        )
    )
```

```
server<-function(input,output){

NoFiles<-length(list.files())
```

Here an empty reactive data.frame

```
outputdata<-reactive(data.frame("file"="file","score"="score"))

filename<-eventReactive(input$new,{ 
            WhichFile<-sample(1:NoFiles,1)
            filename<-list.files()[WhichFile]
            return(filename)
 })

scores<-eventReactive(input$new,{
            return(input$score)
            })
```

Then I would like to append the previous values of the outputdata, with the new values. But it is not working

```
outputdata<-eventReactive(input$new,{
            rbind(outputdata(),filename(),scores())
            })

output$savdat<-renderTable(outputdata())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any advice would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you want the reactivity to occur each time you click on the 'Next file' button.  I rewrote your code to respond just once, using 'ObserveEvent', each time the 'Next file' button is clicked.  The 2nd challenge is permitting values to persist upon each reactive event.  While there are multiple ways to handle this, I chose an expedient technique, the '<<-' assignment statement, to permit the variable 'output data' to persist (this is generally not a good programming technique).  Because the variable 'outputdata' exists in all environments, you'll need to wipe your environment each time you want to run this program.

Here's my rewrite using the same ui you created:

```
ui<-fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    radioButtons(inputId="score",label="Give a score",choices=c(1:9),selected=1),
    actionButton(inputId="new","Next file"),
    tableOutput("savdat")
  )
)
server<-function(input,output){

  NoFiles<-length(list.files())

  setupData <- function(filename,score) {
    data <- data.frame(filename,score,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    return(data)
  }

  observeEvent (input$new, {
    WhichFile<-sample(1:NoFiles,1)
    filename<-list.files()[WhichFile]

    if (!exists(c('outputdata'))) {
      score <- input$score
      outputdata <<- data.frame (filename,score,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    }
    else { 
      outputdata <<- rbind(outputdata,setupData(filename,input$score))
    }

    # Show the table
    output$savdat<-renderTable(outputdata)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I wasn't aware of the <<-